# software similar to Quicken Basic 2000

Tags: software-recommendation

looking for program as close as possible to Quicken Basic 2000, doesn't have to be free..any ideas?
tried gnu, kys, etc, really need a close match

Comment: IMO the closest is kmymoney

Answer (score 0):

Try Gnucash.

> Gnucash provides accounting functions suitable for use by small
>   businesses and individuals. It can track finances in multiple
>   accounts, keeping running and reconciled balances. There is support
>   for customer, vendor and employee processing. It has an X based
>   graphical user interface, double entry, a hierarchy of accounts,
>   expense accounts (categories), and can import Quicken QIF files and
>   OFX files.

To install click [**Gnucash** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnucash/)

<sup>Source:Ubuntu Apps</sup>